# How to map a virtual directory to a website in VS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, master-pages

I am developing a C# VS 2008 website, trying to add a Master file.  I created a virtual directory in IIS housing the "Master" folder, containing the Master files.

Now how do I reference these files from my website in VS?  One problem is I do not know where I need to publish this Master folder to.  Other problem is I do not know how to reference this Master file in my aspx Page directive.

FYI, this master folder is physically located outside of c:\inetpub\ in a totally separate file location.  Is this a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll get away with using a virtual folder for that because any pages that refer to the master page will be in the same application space as the master page (remember that master pages are just user controls).  You create child pages by using Visual Studio or Expression Web to select "create from master page"